# IIS 8 configuration of handlers without verifying file exists

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8, handlers

I am migrating an ASP.NET 2 website from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012.
This means going from IIS 5 to IIS 8.

In IIS 5 I used to map all xml requests to be handled by asp.net (they needed to be served from a dynamic different location), but when trying to set that up using the handlers in IIS 
8, I just get a 404 not found error.

I have verified that my handler is the first in the order and that it's for "unspecified" path types.

How can I set this up so it works in IIS 8 too?

Comment: Can you post your handler xml-node for it? (in %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\config\ApplicationHost.config system.webServer-handlers. Also what kind of 404 do you get? Check the substatus code in the IIS http logs.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the comment. I don't know where to find that substatus error code. Is it just the normal iis log?

Comment: I do see these numbers in hte log file: 404 0 2 5122 1228 59

Comment: So the substatus is 0, which is not helpful, it indicates that the resource was really not found, while any other substatus whould be found not not served due to IIS configuration.